# Сохранение данных textbox и Image

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 3 textbox(c внесенными данными),1 картинка которая загружается пользователем,1 Listbox в котором нужно выбрать вариант ответа. Как и куда сохранить эти данные,чтобы потом ими воспользоватся?

Comment: сначала в модель данных, потом у вас есть огромный выбор : в память, на диск (сериализация), в базу данных, в облако ...  есть даже экзотика : сфотографировать и распечатать )) Расскажите, как именно вы хотите ими воспользоваться

Comment: Хочу сохранять и вызывать из combobox(тем самым реализуя функцию поиска) по нажатию должна появляться страница с этими данными в Textblock.Делаю книгу рецептов,нужно хранение и запись новых рецептов.

Comment: Сохранение по нажатию на кнопку,без сейвдиалога

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста вопрос, ибо сейчас он слишком общий. Вы не понимаете как сохранять или ищете куда сохранять? Или вы вовсе не знаете как работать с контролами и получать из них данные?

Comment: все зависит того хотите ли вы хранить ваши рецепты локально или же централизовано на сервере, чтобы другие пользователи видели добавляемые рецепты. Ваш вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: А вообще по правде ничего не знаю,мне бы пример как сохранить данные из элементов вместе.Если пользователь создает несколько рецептов,то данные должны хранится где то независимо друг от друга.Хочу хранить локально.Программа простая,один пользователь который просто открывает электронную книгу(программу).

Comment: `Binding` в `Properties.Settings.Default.<variable name>` выбрать тип ` *Collection` - и сохранять будет автоматически туда.

Comment: @NewView через свойство объекта хочу это сделать но не могу подцепить,нету моей созданной базы.Но в самом проекте она есть

Comment: Попробуйте сделать для начала это в Settings.Default, потом, когда заработает, экспериментируйте со своим классом базы. И оно должно быть по типу Observable Collection, и поддерживать Notify changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил использовать sql запросы в access

```
 string klantId = nametext.Text; //textbox
            string klantNaam = text.Text; //textbox



            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";


            conn.Open();
            String ticketno = klantId;
            String Purchaseprice = klantNaam;


            String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Рецепты([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice +"')";



            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Плохой пример реализации подключения. В один прекрасный день программа не соединиться с бд и даст вам Exception. Подробнее об [OleDbConnection на оф. сайте Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=xamarinmac-3.0).